# how to get the files from drag and drop, similar as input.Files

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop, data-transfer-objects

When you select a file by clicking `<input type="file" id="file">`, you can use the file in any moment you want by just: `let file=document.querySelector("#file").files[0];`but when using drag/drop as far as I know, you can only use the file inside the drop function handler

```
 targDrop.addEventListener("drop",function(e){let file=e.dataTransfer.files[0]});
```

So, is there any way to get the file similar as `input.Files[0]` even after the drop handler function returns and without uploading file to memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the answer was very straightforward, I just saved the file in a variable and that's it.
I don't know what I was thinking by that time :D

```
let file="";
targDrop.addEventListener("drop",function(e){file=e.dataTransfer.files[0]});
```